# How do I form an SQL query using DATE_SUB to retrieve and post yesterday's data?

Tags: php, sql

Here's my query:

```
$sql = $db->Query("SELECT a.uid, SUM(a.today_clicks) AS clicks, b.login FROM user_clicks a LEFT JOIN users b ON b.id = a.uid WHERE b.login != '' GROUP BY a.uid ORDER BY clicks DESC LIMIT 3");
```

Here's the code i'm using for getting the top 3 users for today:

```
<tr><?
            $tops = $db->FetchArrayAll($sql);
            foreach($tops as $top){
                echo '<td>'.$top['login'].'</td>';
            }
        ?></tr>
```

Which gives me the top 3 user names with the most clicks for today.

Here's my table structure:
Table name :"user_clicks"

6 fields

1. uid
2. module
3. total_clicks
4. today_clicks
5. max_clicks
6. daily_clicks

How can i get the same data but just from a day before?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: in which column can you find yesterday's clicks ? What is the structure of your table ?

Comment: I do not see a time column that would let me know if a record corresponds to yesterday or not. Do you have any column that would give you the date of the record ?

Comment: No. I've checked everywhere , no "Time" column , so i guess i have to change the whole script and include insert into the "Time" column first?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one generic way to filter the columns with a date corresponding to yesterday:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  mytable a
WHERE
    DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), "Y-m-d") = DATE_FORMAT(a.date, "Y-m-d")
```

There is not enough information about your table structure to say how you would apply it in you case. So you will have to figure it out :)

Comment: Hi mika , thanks for your answer. I've tried using your code but nothing happened , can you please write the same code using variables from my code?

Comment: @user347619 - I need you table structure. There is not enough information in your post for me to form that query...